# Requiring a literal period in a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to extract data from a file using egrep:

```
egrep [[:digit:]]\{3,5\}\.[[:digit:]]\{5\} myfile -o
```

This is matching all of the results I want (numbers between 100 and 99999 with five numbers after the decimal place), but it is also matching a time stamp at the beginning of the file, something like `11191335765`. This string has no period, which I've required in my regex.

Why does it match?

General recommendations on improving the above regex are also appreciated, since I am a complete novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is absence of quotes in your `egrep` regex. Without quotes DOT is being interpreted to match anything. Even a string like `11191 12345` will match without quotes since space means any character.

Use this instead:

```
egrep '[[:digit:]]{3,5}\.[[:digit:]]{5}' file
```

**PS:** You don't need to escape `{ and }`

Comment: I escaped the period - how was `\.` being interpreted without the quotes? Also, you have to escape the brackets _unless_ you have quotes. Just using the brackets without quoting gave strange results.

Comment: Without quotes you need to use `\\.` to avoid interpretation but it is best to quote it.